# Navigation bar not showing

Tags: iphone

My MainWindow.xib has a Tab Bar Controller in it with various tabs.  Each tab is set to different xib file.

When tapping on the tabs I change the index of tab bar controller which then loads the appropriate xib.

In one of these xib files I have a navigation controller and its view is set as the main view of the xib and it has various controls on it e.g. tableview etc.

The problem is when I tap on this tab which then loads this xib I don't see the navigation bar - I only see the inner view with tableview etc - so I don't see anything relating to the nav controller!

the nav hidden property is set to false and I am not setting it to true anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tab bar controller xib, you have your tabs defined and each one has the "Nib name" populated, right?

I have mine set up where the tab is a navigation controller and the xib that is loaded is the view controller (vs loading a view controller with a nav controller in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your xib, make sure you choose `Navigation Bar` for `Top Bar` under `Simulated Metrics`.